# Regex matches in Ruby, but not in Java?

Tags: java, regex

Just in an attempt to get more experience with regex (while also making life easier at work) I was trying to parse some filenames in Java.

My string is this: `/home/user/example/Results/ExampleFilePrefix_20140324-0500_OptionalTextThatMightContainNumbers123.csv`

basically the filename will always start with `ExampleFilePrefix_` followed by the timestamp, and sometimes ends with `OptionalTextThatMightContainNumbers123` just depending on how the file was generated. The relevant information I want is the timestamp followed by the optional text if it exists.

I was messing around with various regular expressions and while I can get them all to work with a Ruby regex parser I can't get any of them to work in Java. I didn't keep track of them as I went, but this is my most recent attempt:

`_(\w+-\w+)`

Which works as expected in Ruby: http://rubular.com/r/K2BiboURRo, but doesn't even come close to matching in Java: http://fiddle.re/c7m04

I don't think it's a problem the code I've written due to the fact the online parser doesn't match, but I'll paste it here to be sure.

```
private String extractFileName(String filename) {
    String resultNameBase = "RegexDidntMatch";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("_(\\w+-\\w+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(filename);
    if (matcher.matches() && matcher.find()) {
        resultNameBase = matcher.group(1);
    }
    return resultNameBase;
}
```

As always, thanks to all in advance

Comment: It works exactly as the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) says in Java - `Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of of its only `matcher.find()` And the catch the group `0` instead of `1`.

```
if (matcher.find()) {
    resultNameBase = matcher.group();
}
```

Comment: It looks like this was my initial problem, but my most recent regex was also imperfect. I was able to get the correct match after changing my regex to `_(\\d+-\\w+)`. At that point I can match group 1, which doesn't snag the leading _ while group 0 does.

Answer (score 2):

This part is problem:

```
if (matcher.matches() && matcher.find())
```

`Matcher#matches()` matches complete input string with your regex.

Replace that with:

```
if (matcher.find())
```